# Custom Toolbar not hiding when using scrollFlags

Tags: java, android, scroll, android-toolbar

**What I am trying to do:** I am trying to implement a feature that hides a `Toolbar` when the user scrolls down and makes it visible when the user scrolls up.  Just like in the eBay app, the search bar disappears when the user scrolls down but appears at the top when the user scrolls up.

I have tried using `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` but it doesn't hide the Toolbar when I scroll down.

**XML CODE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <include
        android:id="@+id/searchToolBar"
        layout="@layout/search_toolbar" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/searchBarScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:src="@drawable/camera" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:src="@drawable/camera" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:src="@drawable/camera" />

</LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>



    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</LinearLayout>

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**ToolBar Layouts**

`search_toolbar`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/ebayBlue"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
android:id="@+id/searchtoolBar">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/searchImage"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/search" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/search_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/searchImage"
            android:onClick="searchWindow"
            android:text="Search for anything"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mic_image"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/camera_image"
            android:src="@drawable/mic" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/camera_image"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/camera" />
    </RelativeLayout>

 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

`main toolbar`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/ebayBlue"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
android:id="@+id/toolBar">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ebaylogo"
    android:layout_gravity="left"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**MainActivity.java**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
// ToolBar
Toolbar toolbar;
Toolbar searchToolBar;
// Drawer
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mMenuToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Sets toolbar
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    searchToolBar = findViewById(R.id.searchToolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(searchToolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Main Activity DrawerLayout with Toggle
    mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_activity_drawer_layout);

    // Menu Toggle Button for Drawer
    mMenuToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, 
 R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mMenuToggle);
    mMenuToggle.syncState();

}}
```

**Expected & Actual Results:** The Toolbar `android:id="@+id/searchToolbar"` should be hidden when the user scrolls down and should be visible when the user scrolls up. Right now with the nothing is happening.

Comment: post your toolbar layout

Comment: ok @mohammadRezaAbiri thank you.  I added it.

Comment: I am realizing I should ditch trying to use the LinearLayout as the mockup ToolBar and instead make another ToolBar.  My only issue I imagine moving forward is learning how to implement two toolbars; one with the eBay Logo and NavigationDrawer Button and the other toolbar with the Search that has the ``app:layout_behavior="scroll|enterAlways"`` while the eBay logo toolbar is always visible at top.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I would like to suggest using a [`BottomSheet`](https://medium.com/@oshanm1/how-to-implement-a-search-dialog-using-full-screen-bottomsheetfragment-29ceb0af3d41) instead of your `LinearLayout` which is much harder to implement to achieve the behaviour that you want. The usual implementation of `BottomSheet` does not cover the full screen, however, you can modify this to have the full-screen height.

Here is a [nice implementation](https://medium.com/@oshanm1/how-to-implement-a-search-dialog-using-full-screen-bottomsheetfragment-29ceb0af3d41) which might help.

Comment: I actually realized I should be using a second ToolBar instead.  Because then I can figure out how to use ``app:layout_behavior="scroll|enterAlways"``